# JDBC Discover row based on a value in column

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

Need help from you all in writing up this query.

I have two columns, X and Y.

I have found a value in column Y and I am trying to find its row number.

Alternatively, I was trying to do:

SELECT ID in COLUMN_NAME from TABLE_NAME WHERE COLUMN_NAME2 contains some value I have already retrieved!

```
private int findRow(int value) throws SQLException {
    Connection mysqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

    try {
        String query ="SELECT BUILDING FROM ALLBUILDINGS WHERE BUILDINGNUMBER = 'value'";
        Statement st = mysqlConn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            value = rs.getInt(value);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return value;   
}
```

Can someone tell me how I could do either of the aforementioned?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far? Try [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)

Comment: To check that COLUMN_NAME2 contains some value, you could use a LIKE in your SQL. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: @ThoFin I am doing  while(rs.next()) { row = rs.getInt(value) } where value is the value of the element whose row I am trying to find!

Comment: @FacundoJ I am not looking to find if COLUMN_NAME2 contains some value, I am trying to retrieve the COLUMN_NAME2 corresponding to the COLUMN_NAME1 value, and thought that by finding the row of that value in COLUMN_NAME1 would be the easiest way to find the corresponding value in COLUMN_NAME2

Comment: so why not showing your code? you need the row index, correct? so what is wrong with [getRow](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow())

Comment: I have updated my post now and have added the code. The variable value is the value I have in my column BUILDINGNUMBER, which I know. And what I am trying to do is get its corresponding value from the same table ALL_BUILDINGS, but from a different column, i.e. Building. (the value which I am trying to retrieve is on the same row(but in a different column) as the value I have already found from my BUILDINGNUMBER column)

Comment: By your comment above, why dont you just do "select column_name2 from table_name where column_name1=value".Simple.

Comment: I did try that, doesn't go inside the rs.next() while loop at all! :(

Comment: In that case columne_name1 =value condition does not match to any of the rows in your table.

Comment: It isn't a match, which I am looking to find. It is the Matching value of the value I already have. Say I have found the number 5 from my column1 and am looking for the value of the same row number but in column2

Comment: What you mean by row number ? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Say I have got a table. This table has 20 rows and two columns. I have a value at row 13, column 1 which is 5. What I am looking to get is either the row number(i.e. 13) or the value at row 5 but in column 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103131/discussion-between-professionallyme86-and-user3153278).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

private int findRow(int value) throws SQLException {
    Connection mysqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

```
try {
    String query ="SELECT BUILDING FROM ALLBUILDINGS WHERE BUILDINGNUMBER = ?";
    PreparedStatement st = mysqlConn.prepareStatement(query);
    st.setInt(1,value);

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()) {
        value = rs.getString(1);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}

return value;
```

}

Comment: It was rs.getInt(1) in my case and not rs.getString(1) but I will mark this answer as the correct way to do it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're not trying to find the row index, but instead what the value of the X column is, in the row where Y column = "some_value".

```
SELECT X FROM ALL_BUILDINGS WHERE Y = "some_value";
```

This will match all rows where the Y column is "some_value", and return a corresponding set of values from column X.

Comment: This is exactly what I have and for some very strange reason, it does not work! Could you please check my syntax and see if there is something I've written wrong?

Comment: The query syntax looks fine, assuming the table and column names are correctly spelled. If you are using Visual Studio, you can put a breakpoint and check the value of rs, see if it's empty.

Comment: @Chara I think that shall give an exception on the database side.

Comment: @professionallyme86 I've edited my comment. In fact, I tested it out and it actually allows numbers to be wrapped in single quotes, it just forces an extra cast on SQL's side